# How do I prevent growth of fungus on outer wall of ceramic pots?

Tags: containers, fungus, pots

Many times fungus gets accumulated on the walls of my ceramic pots, it gets too thick & smelly. It is difficult for me to completely remove it with knife.

Is their any way by which we can prevent its growth on ceramic pot ?

I dont want to re-plant all of my ceramic pots plants to plastic pots for this.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't normally see fungus growing on clay pots unless it is in a greenhouse with a high humidity.  Then you see algae and green slimy growths.

However you can see a white powdery exudate on clay pots where the local water has a lot of dissolved salts. If your area has a lot of limestone this will likely be calcium and a mix of other salts. If this is what you have it would be dry to touch, whitish and some can be scraped off with a knife or other hard surface.

To remove take off as much as you can with a wire brush and then apply linseed oil, which will make the powdery deposits invisible.  I use over strength vinegar, or a 10% solution of hydrochloric acid. Rinse well afterward.  When using hydrochloric acid wear goggles, long sleeves and gloves!

Comment: Salts can accumulate from growth mixtures such as miracle grow and many orchid formulas.